# jQuery Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have a multiple select HTML element.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="mult_sel">
   <option value="1">Dog</option>
   <option value="2">Cat</option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following jQuery to capture when a single option in this multiple select is clicked on with the following:

```
$('#mult_sel').click(function(v){
   console.log(v);
});
```

This event triggers as expected, however, I'm not sure how to get the value and text values of the single option that was clicked for a multiple select field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('#mult_sel option').click(function(){
   alert('the value ' $(this).val()); //for get the value
   alert('the text'  $(this).text()); //for get the text
});
```

The `.val()` return the value of the option, and the `.text()` return the text of the option selected.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rbx68/)

Comment: Thank you!! I was using $(this).value() instead of $(this).val()... doh!

Comment: You could also use `this.value` and `this.text`. Shorter and faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RLTN/2/)

```
$('#mult_sel').click(function(event){
    // event.originalEvent.srcElement isn't fully supported
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

there ya go :-) (do check if it's an [option] or a [select] element)

Comment: Use `e.target` instead of `event.originalEvent.srcElement`. The `.srcElement` is a non-standard IE construct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Select2 JQuery

you must download the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2/tags) and copy the dist directory to your project.

Include the following lines of code in the `<head>` section of your HTML.

```
<link href="../css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Initialize Select2 on the `<select>` element that you want to make it multiple select boxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#select2-multiple').select2();
</script>
```

Example Code (Remember to declared with the multiple attribute)

```
<select class="select2-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="WWL">Wong Wai Ling</option>
  <option value="AE">Alessia Enzler</option>
  <option value="ASL">A-Young SON LAuren</option>
</select>
```